# Host Exchange secondary server in different datacenter

Tags: exchange, exchange-2013, exchange-2016

I have a standalone multi-role exchange 2016 in my dc
We are planning to make this a highly available infrastructure and move the secondary to a different DC.
Basically keeping primary and secondary exchange in 2 different datacenter.

Could someone let me know the possibilities and difficulties ..and advice in the setup. Consideration for the setup.

**Exchange 2016**, one in primary location another in secondary location.

Internet speed BW  **10mbps** between the datacenters.

**Single AD** at primary location, planning for L2 VPN to extend the VLAN

LB, 
mostly Microsoft NLB hosted at primary site, having both exchagne managed under same pool in primary site.(also considering Netscaler as LB for CAS Role as teh sites are geographically far)

```
If a different LB needs to be used, please suggest.
```

OWA will be used.

Outlook Client will be used.

User count : 250+

We need to set up Active/Active DAG with mailboxes spread in both servers.

Thanks
//PASHa

Comment: Can you add more infos please? How many users, how many disk space is used. Can you give us more infos about your AD environment (e.g. sites). Additional is OWA used, did you have already a hardware loadbalancer? Did you need to load balance incoming SMTP, means did you plan to change your MX record to include two IPs... with so basic infos its hardly not possible to provide anything else as a very simple and basic setup.

Answer (score 2):

With so less infos its only possible to provide a basic setup. Inside the 2nd DC you will setup a 2nd Exchange Server. Then you will create a DAG including both Exchange server and inside this DAG you will create the mailboxes, so that they are synced between the two Exchange server (see [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd638129(v=exchg.160).aspx)).

But in your question I do not see infos regarding incoming emails. So here are some basic stuff:

Incoming emails are handled via an MX Record. To do a kind of HA here you would then add two IPs with the same preferences. So if one Server is down the other one could be used.

For stuff like OWA/OAW you might wish to come up with an hardware/software load balancer (but to give you a detailed answer here we need to know more infos about how many users).

Additional if you have internal devices like scan2mail systems you might need HA here as well. This depends on your needs and without further infos its also not easy to answer. One possible option might be a simple round robin with both internal Exchange server so that the device (hopefully) pick up the working one if it discovered that the other one is not working as expected.

So in total ... we need much more info's from you if this souldn´t be only a basic answer.